# RxSwift Conditional Observable

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift

I'm new to RxSwift and had a question about the Observables.
In particular, I'm trying to have an Observable (based on **viewDidAppear**) emit only when a subview is visible (some boolean flag is true).

So far, both the **skip**- and **take**- operators (and their like) looked like the most promising. The only problem is, this subview can appear/disappear every time a user visits the parent view (depending on some conditions).

Based on my limited understanding, the above operators take into effect when the condition is meant once (and will complete). Is there something I'm misunderstanding or maybe there is a way to achieve my goal?

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> The essence of functional reactive programming is to specify the dynamic behavior of a value completely at the time of declaration.
> -- [Heinrich Apfelmus](https://apfelmus.nfshost.com/blog/2011/03/28-essence-frp.html)

So the question is, what is the dynamic behavior of the value you are defining?

In order to make a sub-view of your VC's view appear and disappear, its `isHidden` property needs to be updated at the right times. So what are the triggers that cause this sub-view to appear and disappear? Turn those into Observables, combine them with some logic and bind that `Observable<Bool>` to the subview's `rx.isHidden` property.

Unfortunately, you haven't given enough information for me to help with that, but if you update your question, I will update my answer.

In the mean time, I'll leave you with this example from one of my production apps. The invariant is that the `benefitKeysView` should only be visible if there is more than one `benefitColor`.

```
func setupBenefitKeys(benefitKeysView: UIView, disposeBag: DisposeBag, benefitColors: Observable<BenefitColorsData>) {
    benefitColors
        .map { $0.benefitColors.count < 2 }
        .startWith(true)
        .bind(to: benefitKeysView.rx.isHidden)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}

struct BenefitColorsData {
    let benefitColors: [UIColor]
}
```

Comment: Well-detailed answer to a raw question. Although, It might be a dumb question of mine, but what is the use of disposeBag in this case?

Comment: The assumption is that the dispose bag is coming from a view controller. Its job is to dispose of all the subscriptions when the view controller retaining it deinits. It is highly likely that the `benefitColors` observable will complete when that happens so really the dispose bag is just there as a safe-guard...